# TFT touch, 4bit data transfer

Tags: 1-wire

I followed instructions to get my TFT to work.

[image: TFT photo]

I want to use other pins on the Arduino Uno for other I/O, so how can I use 4-bit data transfer for the TFT touchscreen?

Comment: Hi Veno, welcome to StackExchange. Unfortunately, it is not clear what you are asking. Are you asking how to get the touch screen to work? Try [TFTLCD-Library](https://github.com/adafruit/TFTLCD-Library). You say that you followed instructions... Which instructions did you follow to get our TFT to work? Can you edit your post and provide a link? Also, if you have another question relating to building an "antenna analyzer", then please ask a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You read the datasheet for the chip that is on your TFT display (whatever that is) and find if it even supports a 4-bit mode.  It probably doesn't. I have a large number of TFT screens here and I don't recall any of them using parallel 4-bit.  It sounds like you actually want a TFT screen that works of SPI rather than a parallel interface.  Those *are* available, but by using SPI the screen updates are considerably slower.

Comment: Yes,it will be slower with ISP, I want to test 4bit code on my TFT, can u help me

Comment: @VenuGopalRaoAggress No, I can't. Not unless you tell us *what your TFT is*. That means the exact model number of the chip that is on the TFT screen itself (ILIxxxx, SSDxxxx, SDxxxx, XPxxxx, etc) and how the TFT screen is wired up to the Arduino (schematic of the TFT screen's carrier shield).

Comment: Chip is 7783, Tannq

Comment: Not familiar with the ST7783 ( I assume it's Sitronix). I know the ST7781 and ST7785 and as I suspected, neither support a 4 bit interface. They do have an SPI mode, but the carrier shield has to be wired right for it.  I would suggest shopping around for an SPI TFT screen.  You won't find one with a 4-bit parallel interface - they simply don't exist.  8 bit, 16 bit or 18 bit. Never 4 bit.